# elasticsearch 5.X + searchkick(rails) configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, searchkick

I'm in the process of upgrading my elasticsearch instance from V1.7 to 5.3 and I'm running into some errors when starting my reindex. From what I can tell most models can index just fine but there are a couple I had that used more advanced settings that don't seem to be working. Here's an example of one of my models(brand.rb):

```
searchkick word_start: [:name],
  merge_mappings: true,
  mappings: searchkick_mappings,
  settings: searchkick_settings

def search_data
  attributes.merge(
    geography: self.geography ? self.geography.name : "",
    geography_breadcrumb: self.geography ? self.geography.breadcrumb : "",
    producer_name: self.producer.name
  )
end
```

the searchkick_mappings and searchkick_settings are defined in another file that is included in my model. Here's the code:

```
def searchkick_mappings
  {
    brand: {
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: 'text',
          analyzer: 'standard',
          fields: {
            autocomplete: {
              type: 'text',
              analyzer: 'autocomplete'
            },
            folded: {
              type: 'text',
              analyzer: 'folded'
            },
            delimited: {
              type: 'text',
              analyzer: 'delimited'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
end

def searchkick_settings
  {
    analysis: {
      filter: {
        autocomplete_filter: {
          type: 'edge_ngram',
          min_gram: 1,
          max_gram: 20
        },
        delimiter_filter: {
          type: 'word_delimiter',
          preserve_original: true
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        folded: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['standard','lowercase','asciifolding']
        },
        delimited: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'whitespace',
          filter: ['lowercase','delimiter_filter']
        },
        autocomplete: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['standard','lowercase', 'asciifolding', 
                  'autocomplete_filter']
        }
      }
    }
  }
end
```

The only change I made from when it was working in V1.7 -> 5.3 is that I had to change the 'type' field from "String" to "text" as it seems they removed the string type in favor of a text and keyword type, where text is analyzed and keywords are not. The error i'm receiving when I run bundle exec searchkick:reindex:all is saying there is an unknown parameter 'ignore_above'. From reading the documentation it seems that parameter is only for keyword fields and not text but I am not adding that parameter in my custom mappings so I don't see why it would be there.

Let me know if you need to see more code/need to know more. I'll gladly edit OP/comment whatever is helpful.